# Can I force Microsoft Word 2013 to only Undo 1 keystroke at a time?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

In case there's a different solution for my use case, here are my reasons:

I often use Word for writing documents with lots of lists, and when I accidentally hit enter, instead of ctrl-enter, I want to be able to just hit ctrl-z and try it again.

Instead, half the time it will wipe out a bunch of text on the previous line - commonly, a whole sentence or more. So instead I have to hit backspace multiple times to remove the new bullet item, however many indents, and then the newline.

Comment: As I mentioned, it generally takes 4 or 5 backspaces. Which gets frustrating. Word does so much auto formatting at a single keystroke, but I can't always remove it as efficiently.

Comment: Good question, I've often been frustrated by this too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot force Word to undo one character at a time.

**Alternative 1:**

Slightly less annoying(?) -- <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, then <kbd>Del</kbd>.

**Alternative 2:**

Create a macro that you assign to a keyboard shortcut and/or a button of your choice...

Either a macro of the needed backspaces, or the key sequence mentioned in alternative 1, or a few lines of code that will delete the current line:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
```