# How to change Word 'undo' behavior to not be character-by-character?

Tags: microsoft-word, undo

If I type something in Microsoft Word 2016, then press Undo (ctrl+z), it 'undo's what I typed, *one character* at a time. This is not normal, and is quite frustrating. Normal behaviour is to undo the last word or sentence. So if I want to undo a whole paragraph, I either have to press and hold Undo and risk going too far, or press Undo a million times.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/822731/can-i-force-microsoft-word-2013-to-only-undo-1-keystroke-at-a-time/822739#822739) chap seems to have the opposite problem, but that's of no help to me.

Searching the Web, I came across two potential solutions: disable Overtype mode (it's in Insert mode already), or turn off page numbers (doesn't work).

Apart from reinstalling Office, **what do I have to do to get the normal Undo behaviour back?**

Comment: If you click the Undo button on the screen using the mouse, does it behave differently than pressing CTRL+Z? What type of computer are you using (desktop, laptop, Surface pro etc.)? Can you test with a different keyboard?

Comment: It's definitely not the keyboard. Clicking the Undo button in the Ribbon results in identical behaviour. Clicking the dropdown list that lists every history item reveals a bunch of single-character entries: "Typing g. Typing o. Typing d. Typing ' '. Typing k" etc. My computer is a laptop (a Surface Pro 3, to be precise), but I usually use Word with an external keyboard, monitor, and mouse.

Comment: Is it possible you're typing really slowly? I was able to reproduce a `Typing "a"`, `Typing "b"`, `Typing "c"` behavior when I paused for a second between each letter.

Comment: Nope, definitely not.

Comment: Go figure: the problem disappeared on its own when I updated Windows. I don't know what caused the problem, nor what fixed it, either.

Comment: Updating Windows can now also update Office products, if you check a box to allow it.  Might be the default now, I'm not sure.  The insert vs overtype mode might have been a key detail.  That's toggled by the insert key, right?  If you're in the not-normal mode (I don't know which is which), you might have been an edgecase as far as testing.

Comment: @Dan: I was in the regular mode. The Insert key hasn't toggled insert/overtype mode for at least three versions of Word. There's a setting to make it do that, but it's off by default, because really, who even uses Overtype mode? I only ever had it in Insert mode. And I forgot that Windows handles updates for Office, as well. It was probably some corrupt file somewhere that got fixed with the update. Ah well, we'll probably never know.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/undo-entire-word/de7f6e46-701c-4716-b9f2-5f777f9e788a) and [this forum at PC Review](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/undo-more-than-just-one-letter-at-a-time.3970193/) if you remove page numbers and overtyping, it changes the behaviour of the undo command.

Microsoft Answer:

> In an existing file (.docx), toggling between insert and overtype is not always an option (even if its activated via options).  In these instances, they only way to change the behaviour is to remove the page numbers at either the bottom or top of the page (after which the behaviour switches from undo by character to the desired undo by word). Curiously, after deleting the page numbers, the ability to toggle between insert and overtype is now possible.

PC Review Answer:

> I may have stumbled upon the cause of this annoying behavior. Apparently when in "Overwrite" mode, keystrokes are taken as unique actions since they typically replace one letter with another. When typing at the end of a paragraph, the following paragraph is not overwritten; however, the keystrokes are still undone one at a time. To change the behavior, double-click "OVR" in the status bar or press the Insert key on the keyboard. This will toggle Overwrite mode between on and off. When it is off, the "OVR" will be greyed out and you will be able to undo whole blocks of text as one action.

I can replicate the issue by both enabling Overtyping and inserting page numbers. So perhaps try disabling both:

*To disable page numbers:* Click the Insert tab at the top, followed by Page Number in the Header & Footer section, then click Remove Page Numbers.

*To disable Overtyping:* Click File, then Options, then Advanced. Locate the Use Overtype Mode checkbox and ensure this is not selected. Furthermore, you can disable the Insert key to activate it by unchecking the box above.

Hope this helps somewhat.

EDIT: Just noticed you have Overtype and page numbers disabled already. I believe you can hold down the undo keys to remove single keys faster, but other than that I'll continue to search. Will update answer once I find something.

Comment: Unless you want to do it for posterity, don't bother, because the problem disappeared on its own (see comments on question).